# do-while loop still running even thought the conditional is false

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [];
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);

for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr2.push(arr1[index]);
    do {
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);
        console.log(arr2.includes(arr1[index])); //thís is to see the result
    } while (arr2.includes(arr1[index]))
}

console.log('arr2: ', arr2);
```

I want to make the new unordered array from the first array. But when I run this code, the loop becomes an infinite loop although the conditional is false. My question is the reason make the loop still running with the false conditional?

[image]

Comment: Your code will hang inside the last do-while loop forever since at that point, every element has been pushed to the new array. Shuffling an array doesn't require a check like that if you remove the element from the original array (or a copy of it).

Comment: Add a `console.log()` in the outer loop and you'll see that the inner loop is not running when the condition is false.

Comment: Make a simple copy of the original array and then perform a Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array for the correct ways to shuffle an array.

Comment: I understand the problem. I will try again with the solution you gave me. Thanks you for all your help ☺️